# MagicalRecord delete and then fetch with new data

Tags: objective-c, magicalrecord

What I want to do is every 2 weeks I want to clean the database and fill with new data.

So I thought I could do it like this:

```
[Entity MR_truncateAll];
[Entity MR_truncateAll];
[self saveContext];
```

and then after that a internet fetch.

The database is empty but stays empty. I think it has something to do with that truncateAll goes on a different thread.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to do it on a background queue, then use this method instead:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagaedObjectContext *localContext) {
     [Entity MR_truncateAllInContext:localContext];

}];
```

This code will automatically run this block with the proper setup required for background queue use and save the deletes to the data store.